# Can someone explain to me this implementation of Tile Coding using Hash Tables?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, python, implementation, function-approximation, tile-coding

The code below is adapted from [this implementation](https://github.com/kamenbliznashki/sutton_barto/blob/master/tiles3.py).

```
from math import floor

basehash = hash

class IHT:
    "Structure to handle collisions"
    def __init__(self, sizeval):
        self.size = sizeval
        self.overfullCount = 0
        self.dictionary = {}

    def count (self):
        return len(self.dictionary)

    def getindex (self, obj, readonly=False):
        d = self.dictionary
        if obj in d: return d[obj]
        elif readonly: return None
        size = self.size
        count = self.count()
        if count >= size:
            if self.overfullCount==0: print('IHT full, starting to allow collisions')
            self.overfullCount += 1
            return basehash(obj) % self.size
        else:
            d[obj] = count
            return count

def hashcoords(coordinates, m, readonly=False):
    if type(m)==IHT: return m.getindex(tuple(coordinates), readonly)
    if type(m)==int: return basehash(tuple(coordinates)) % m
    if m==None: return coordinates


def tiles(ihtORsize, numtilings, floats, ints=[], readonly=False):
    """returns num-tilings tile indices corresponding to the floats and ints"""
    qfloats = [floor(f*numtilings) for f in floats]
    Tiles = []
    for tiling in range(numtilings):
        tilingX2 = tiling*2
        coords = [tiling]
        b = tiling
        for q in qfloats:
            coords.append( (q + b) // numtilings )
            b += tilingX2
        coords.extend(ints)
        Tiles.append(hashcoords(coords, ihtORsize, readonly))
    return Tiles

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tc=IHT(4096)
    tiles = tiles(tc, 8, [0, 0.5], ints=[], readonly=False)
    print(tiles)
```

I'm trying to figure out how the function `tiles()` works. It implements tile coding, which is explained in ["Reinforcement Learning: An Introduction" (2020) Sutton and Barto on page 217](http://incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2020.pdf#page=239).

So far I've figured out:

- `qfloats` rescales the floating numbers to be the largest integer less than or equal to the original floating number, these are then re-scaled by the number of tilings.
- Then, for each tiling, a list is created, the first element of the list is the tiling number, followed by the coordinates of the floats for that tiling, i.e. each of the re-scaled numbers is offset by the tiling number, `b` and integer divided by `numtilings`.
- Finally, `hashcoords` first checks the dictionary `d` to see if this list has appeared before, if it has it returns the number relating to that list. It not it either creates a new entry with that list at the key and the count as the value or if the count is more than or equal to the size it adds one to `overfullCount` and returns `basehash(obj) % self.size`.

I'm struggling to understand two parts:

1. What is the `tilingX2` part doing?
2. Why is `tilingX2` added to `b` after the first coordinate has been calculated? It seems to me that each coordinate should be treated separately
3. And why by a factor of 2?
4. What is the expression `basehash(obj) % self.size` doing? I'm quite new to the concept of hashing. I know that, generally, they create a unique number for a given input (up to a limit), but I'm really struggling to understand what is going on in the line above.

Comment: Hello. Welcome to AI SE :) Your post was not properly formatted, so I took the time to format it properly. Please, take a look at https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/formatting and at the current version of your post so that you know how a "good-looking" posts looks :) Take also a look at this https://ai.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1654/2444 if you have some time.

Comment: To partially answer your 4th question. The operator `a % b` is the [modulo operator](https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-science/cryptography/modarithmetic/a/what-is-modular-arithmetic), i.e. it returns the remainder of the _integer_ division between `a` and `b`. So, say that you have `a = 4` and `b = 3`, then `a % b = 4 % 3 = 1`, because `3 * 1 + 1 = 4`.

Comment: So, basically, `basehash(obj) % self.size` is a number that is ensured to never be greater or equal to `self.size`. So, if you have an list of size `self.size`, you can index it with `basehash(obj) % self.size` and be sure you will not get an `IndexError`.